# IIS – Windows Authentication – Authenticating self

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-authentication

I have an iis6 .net website which requires windows authentication (Anonymous disabled).  The website has a dedicated application pool running as NETWORK SERVICE.

The website contains a requirement to perform http requests against itself.

When the website issues a HTTP get against its self, a 401 is returned as the site is not passing any security credentials in the request. I can see this in the iis web logs.

I want to enable the website to recognize itself as intranet and automatically pass its authentication token (NETWORK SERVICE) with the resource request. Is this possible?

Many Thanks, 
Adam